# Decode Ways Python (Facebook Interview problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

[Link](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-ways/) to this problem :

A message containing letters from A-Z can be encoded into numbers using the following mapping:

```
'A' -> "1"
'B' -> "2"
.
.
.
'Z' -> "26"
```

To decode an encoded message, all the digits must be grouped then mapped back into letters using the reverse of the mapping above (there may be multiple ways).

For example, "11106" can be mapped into:

- "AAJF" with the grouping (1 1 10 6)
- "KJF" with the grouping (11 10 6)
- Note that the grouping (1 11 06) is invalid because "06" cannot be
  mapped into 'F' since "6" is different from "06".

Given a string s containing only digits, return the number of ways to decode it.

The answer is guaranteed to fit in a 32-bit integer.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: s = "12"
Output: 2
Explanation: "12" could be decoded as "AB" (1 2) or "L" (12).
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input: s = "226"
Output: 3
Explanation: "226" could be decoded as "BZ" (2 26), "VF" (22 6), or "BBF" (2 2 6).
```

**My code:**

```
class Solution:
    def numDecodings(self, s: str) -> int:
        arr = [char for char in s]
        
        if len(arr) == 0:
            return 1
        
        if len(arr) == 1 and arr[0] == '0':
            return 0
        
        if arr[0] == '0':
            return 0
        
        if arr[-1] == '0':
            arr.pop()
            
        if len(arr) == 1 and arr[0] != '0':
            return 1
        
        if len(arr) > 1:
        
            count = 1
            for i in range(0,len(s)-1):
                if arr[i] == '0':
                    continue
                curr = []
                curr.append(arr[i])
                curr.append(arr[i+1])

                currStr = "".join(curr)

                num = int(currStr)
                if num <= 26:
                    count += 1
        return count
```

**Input**

```
"2101"
```

**Output**

```
4
```

**Expected**

```
1
```

How can 2101 be decoded in just one way?

Comment: I think the reason may have something to do with the fact that the only time `0` may appear in a string of digits is in `10` or `20`.  According to the problem, `0` cannot precede a digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only valid decoding of 2101 is as 2 10 1. There's nothing else you can do with the 0.

Comment: I guess my approach is totally wrong and i should just throw in the trash rather than trying to make it work, what do you think?

Comment: @farziAccount420: That is an accurate assessment. Your code is doing something completely different from what the problem definition is asking for. Here's a hint for what you should be doing: try to express the number of decodings for a string `s` in terms of the number of decodings for `s[:-2]` and `s[:-1]`.